# How to add an event notification to an imported Bucket

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am writing the `cdk` script by `typescript`.

I would like to pick up the already exist `bucket` and set as trigger for `lambda`

```
const _bucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(this,"frombucket",`vr-${targetEnv}-resource-up-bk`);

lambdaFromContainer_.addEventSource(new S3EventSource(_bucket, { 
  events: [ s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],

}));
```

`s3.Bucket.fromBucketName` returns `IBucket` and There error occurs `S3EventSource(_bucket`

```
Argument of type 'IBucket' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bucket'.
  Type 'IBucket' is missing the following properties from type 'Bucket': autoCreatePolicy, lifecycleRules, metrics, cors, and 31 more.ts(2345)
```

How can I fix this problem?

However when I made new Bucket ,There is no error.

```
const _bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'cdk-out-bk', {
      bucketName: `vr-${targetEnv}-resource-up-bk`,
}
lambdaFromContainer_.addEventSource(new S3EventSource(_bucket, { 
  events: [ s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],

}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because CDK cannot modify imported resources. This is reflected by the limited number of properties available on `IBucket`. You would need to create the bucket with CDK and add the notification in the same CDK app.

Refer to the following question:
[Adding managed policy aws with cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841655)

That being said, you can do anything you want with custom resources. And it just so happens that there's a custom resource for adding event notifications for imported buckets. You use it like this:

```js
bucket.addEventNotification(s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new s3n.LambdaDestination(myLambda));
```

Example taken from the docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3-readme.html#importing-existing-buckets

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , Now I understand the reason, at this moment. I was so new to aws , thanks to  your help.

Comment: please explain: do I need to create lambda in CDK to trigger by existing bucket or I should also define bucket in CDK stack?